# LINQ get last 12 months

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

how would i pull the

> last 12(months) records filtered by
>   ServiceId, ordered by most recent

using linq given this db table data:

```
 - Date         ServiceId     Views     Clicks
 - 2009-03-01       3         88107     244223
 - 2009-03-01       5         41563     94770
 - 2009-03-01       7         24165     45378
 - 2009-03-01       8         16415     24311
 - 2009-03-01       4         50341     127114
 - 2009-04-01       3         70646     211999
 - 2009-04-01       5         40380     102241
 - 2009-04-01       7         23905     40768
 - 2009-04-01       8         18996     29220
 - 2009-04-01       4         45685     112635
 - 2009-05-01       3         81044     215753
 - 2009-05-01       5         46273     121343
 - 2009-05-01       7         25744     41578
 - 2009-05-01       8         21122     32607
 - 2009-05-01       4         54349     126914
 - 2009-06-01       3         74045     201224
 - 2009-07-01       3         60558     175043
 - 2009-07-01       5         28802     69091
 - 2009-07-01       7         16250     33784
 - 2009-07-01       4         36265     88727
 - 2009-08-01       3         59030     170027
 - 2009-08-01       5         27923     63875
 - ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this help?

"someServiceId" would be the service id you want to filter on.

*12 months ago from now:*

```
from x in data
where x.Date > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12) && x.ServiceId == someServiceId
orderby x.Date descending
select x;
```

*12 months ago from most recent entry:*

```
from x in data
let m = data.OrderByDescending(x.Date).First()
where x.Date > m.Date.AddMonths(-12) && x.ServiceId == someServiceId
orderby x.Date descending
select x;
```

I haven't ran this through a compiler but hopefully it should get you in the right direction.

Comment: this works but it gives me only 6 months :(. and i see why, it's because my last date is 9/1/2010. therefor i can't be useing DateTime.Now.. i have to start from the most recent. ??

Comment: Do you mean 12 months from the most recent entry? or 12 months from today? If it's the former let me just update my answer.

Comment: So i guess i would have to do this: .Where(item => item.Month > item.Month.Max()..but not sure how

Comment: 12 months from the last (most recent date) in the table

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = DataContext.YourTable.Where(e => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12) < e.Date)
                     .Where(e => e.ServiceId == filterServiceId)
                     .OrderByDescending(e => e.Date)
```

Comment: There's no such method: `TimeSpan.FromYears()`.  It only goes up to `TimeSpan.FromDays()`.

Comment: sorry I did that from memory, it make sense since Timepan is not aware of the duration of months etc... I'll correct that